# NodeJs support encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, snmp

I am new to NodeJS, developing my first server app, which talks with snmp protocol support device, I received data from device without problem, but looks like strings with description of device is in unsupported encoding for my local language, how to add support for my local language in NodeJS?

[image: Postman response]

Comment: What is your local language? Do you know the encoding? Any educated guesses?

Comment: The type of string OCTET String, it is from snmp protocol, found this for csharp https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/tutorials/octet-strings.html. How to do it in JS...

Comment: That doesn't help. "Octet" is another word for "byte". _What is your local language?_

Comment: Russian, Cyrillic

Comment: Thank you! Then you might want to try the KOI8-R or CP1251 encodings.

Comment: Thanks for help, CP1251 encoding is working.

Comment: Great – I made that an answer you can accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Russian, Cyrillic writing, common encodings are KOI8-R or CP1251.

In this case, apparently CP1251 was the correct guess.